# Creating a repo server with older Ubuntu release

Tags: 16.04, localrepository

I have an installer service that uses the Ubuntu mirror to install a cluster of servers that use Ubuntu as the OS.  The packages that were bundled with the application/installer are not compatible now with the more recent packages updated in Xenial amd64 16.04.04 and above.
Is there a way to create a local repo server that has the updates only to version 16.04.03?
I haven't found a way to do that anywhere so far.

Changing the application to fix the incompatibilities is not an option.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/301745)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: @stumblebee: Although certainly related I'm not sure that this question and its answer are actually helpful for a repository mirror.

Comment: Yeah, the responses so far are something similar, but not actually what I need to do.